# Return a sorted List<Object> where first item value is always empty

Tags: java, linked-list

Working with a list of `Object` where one of the item has an empty `String`. Trying to write method which would return a sorted list. By sorting means the first item value of the list should always be an empty `String`.

Since I don't want to manipulate the unsorted list, I am creating a new list to sort.

So far my code is:

```
   private List<LoggerConfig> sort(List<LoggerConfig> unSortedList) {

    List<LoggerConfig> sortedList = new ArrayList<LoggerConfig>(unSortedList);

    //What to do here

    return sortedList;
}
```

Looked at lot of `SO` posts but very confused.

Comment: If i understand the question correctly: You want to sort the list, but one element's ``String`` value is empty and after sorting you want that element to be the first element?

Comment: Sorted list should have the the first element's `String` value to be empty, which exists in the unsorted list. So not sure if sorting required or just check the elements of unsortedlist and put the element when condition matches to the zero index of the sortedlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trust the `String.compareTo` to match the order you seek. Here is a Comparator :

```
new Comparator<LoggerConfig>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(LoggerConfig o1, LoggerConfig o2) {
    return (o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()));
  }
};
```

or directly implementing `Comparable` in the specific class (here Dummy)

```
class Dummy implements Comparable<Dummy>{

    String name;

    public int compareTo(Dummy o) {
        return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
}
```

The why :

The `String.compareTo` check the first characters of both to find a difference (until the smallest length of both), if they match, the lengths are use to make the difference, the longest will be after the shortest (`shortest.compareTo(longuest)` will return an negative value (the length difference)).

In this case, `"".compareTo("abc")`, there is no character in the empty String, so the first check is skipped and the length is use to compare the `String`s, so an empty `String` will always be seen as first compare to any "non-empty" `String`

An example with the previous `Dummy` class (just need to add the Constructor `Dummy(String)`:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<Dummy> dummies = new LinkedList<Dummy>();
       dummies.add(new Dummy("abc.com.core"));
       dummies.add(new Dummy(""));
       dummies.add(new Dummy("abc.com.core.def"));

       System.out.println("BEFORE : " + dummies);
       Collections.sort(dummies);
       System.out.println("AFTER : " + dummies);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
BEFORE : [abc.com.core, , abc.com.core.def]
AFTER : [, abc.com.core, abc.com.core.def]
```

Comment: You're correct, ``String``'s own ``compareTo`` already considers and empty ``String`` less than any other value.

Comment: But not sure if it works because my test fails. 
        @Test
    public void testSort() {

        List<LoggerConfig> unsortedList = makeUnsortedList();
        EasyMock.replay(item1,item2,item3);

        List<LoggerConfig> sortedList = tested.sort(unsortedList);

        assertTrue(sortedList.get(0).getName().isEmpty());
        assertTrue(sortedList.get(1).equals("com.abc.core") || sortedList.get(1).equals("com.abc.core.AA"));
        assertTrue(sortedList.get(2).equals("com.fwk.core") || sortedList.get(2).equals("com.abc.core.AA"));

    }

Comment: Could you edit your question with the test correctly indented ;) comments are bad to show code. I will test it a soon as I go home (1hour)

Comment: @shaz but you didn't call `Collections.sort` with the custom `Comparator` in your example.

Comment: @AxelH: It is called in the test `tested.sort(unsortedList);`

Comment: @shaz I don't know `Sorter` I only have found a `JUnit` interface but you can't build it so what his it ? But I would guess you didn't implement the `Comparator` or override the `compareTo` method to compare the instance based on the `getName()`

Comment: @AxelH `Sorter.java` is a private class I created where the method `sort(unsortedList)` is implemented, which should return the sortedList.In a way I was doing a simple implementation of the unit test written by using `EasyMock` for `JUnit`. Not sure if the `sort()` method implementation is correct to pass the test. Or the error I am getting is a `EasyMock` error instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143941/discussion-between-axelh-and-shaz).

Answer (score 1):

You can place this condition in your comparator so that elements with an empty value are considered "less" than other elements, so that it shows up at the beginning of the sorted list. Try something like this:

```
Collections.sort(sortedList, new Comparator<LoggerConfig>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(LoggerConfig o1, LoggerConfig o2) {
    if(o1.getName().isEmpty(){
      return -1;
    }
    if(o2.getName().isEmpty(){
      return 1;
    }
    return (o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()));
  }
});
```

I didn't test this, but this should make the idea clear. If the empty element shows up at the end of the list, swap the `-1` and the `1`.

If your List is huge and sorting takes a lot of time, it might be a better idea to remove the empty element before sorting,  then sort, then place the element at the beginning.

Comment: This is basicly what `String.compareTo(String)` would return

Comment: @AxelH if ``String``'s ``compareTo`` handles empty Strings the same way, OP's comparator is enought. The question sounds like it doesn't work as intended though.

Comment: Well, he asked "_Would I need the comparison here as follows?_" so I suspect the code was not tried. I quickly run a snippet with `String` to be sure because I wasn't sure, see my answer if you want. I will add the code

Answer (score 1):

The `Comparator` solution seems feasible to me; what you're missing is implementing the `compare` method so that it does what you want.

```
Collections.sort(sortedList, new Comparator<LoggerConfig>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(LoggerConfig o1, LoggerConfig o2) {
        if(o1.getName().equals("")){
            return -1;
        } else if(o2.getName().equals("")) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return (o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()));
        }
    }
});
```

As per [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), the `Comparator` has a `compare` method that returns an int which is

- less than 0 if the first argument is less than the second
- 0 if the arguments are equal
- greater than 0 if the first argument is greater than the second

So the `Comparator` you need should return the comparison of the two strings if they're both different from `""`, and -1 (or 1) if the first (or second) String is empty.

Comment: We have the same idea. Impossible not to upvote this :)

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing :)

Comment: This is basicly what `String.compareTo(String)` would return

Comment: This is comparing two items from the same list. Don't understand.How would  it return the new list (sorted) where the first element's value is empty? Still need the iterator?

Comment: @shaz ``Collections.sort`` uses the ``Comparator`` instance to check each of the list's entries against each other. When ``Collections.sort`` is finished, the ``List`` you gave to it as a parameter is sorted. If you require a new instance of the List, create a copy of it before sorting.

Comment: It is doing a bubble sort, I believe, to compare each items with the next one.